# finished messages in TLS version 1.0

Tags: openssl, ssl

JKJS

Can anyone tell what is seq_num in below line?

```
HMAC_hash(MAC_write_secret, seq_num + TLSCompressed.type + TLSCompressed.version + TLSCompressed.length + TLSCompressed.fragment));
```

RFC 2246 defines it like this:

```
seq_num
   The sequence number for this record.
```

But where is sequence number in TLS record?Where are these numbers generated and assigned to record?

JKJS
Hardik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sequence numbers will be zero for the finished record and from then on will be incremented for each record.

These are not sent along with the record, but should be maintained by the implementation and used for HMAC generation for each record. If a TLS record arrives out of sequence, then the MAC verification will fail as the sequence number used for MAC generation at the peer side and the sequence number expected by the self side will not be same.

Comment: JKJS. I understood it like this: Each encrypted message( these excludes handshake messages which are not encrypted. ) has a unique sequence number which starts from 0 from finished message.